# When does copy_file actually return false?

Tags: c++, c++17

The simple version of [`std::filesystem::copy_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) has the following signature:

```
bool copy_file(const path& from, const path& to);
```

The return value is described as:

> true if the file was copied, false otherwise.

Which makes generally sense and you would want to wrap the call with an if and report errors if the operation failed, like so:

```
if (!fs::copy_file(inputImage, outputImage))
{
    LOG(error) << "Failed to copy file:" << inputImage << " ==> " << outputImage;
}
```

**But**, if you look at the documentation for the exceptions:

> The overload that does not take a std::error_code& parameter throws filesystem_error on underlying OS API errors, constructed with from as the first path argument, to as the second path argument, and the OS error code as the error code argument.

This leads me to my question, if failures, such as insufficient permissions, file locked and other file system errors result in an exception, in what conditions does the simple `copy_file` ever return with `false`?

Comment: The documentation (your link) mentions: _The non-throwing overloads return false if an error occurs_. So this bool return is not dedicated to this kind of error

Comment: Standard document is very specific for error handling and this part isn't difficult to read. You can refer to it directly. 30.11.6 and 30.11.14.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to handle your errors with `filesystem`. This is basically inherited from boost. You either put the error in that `error_code` reference, or you take it from an exception.

Basically, the version that takes a parameter is guaranteed not to throw, and the version that doesn't take a parameter throws on error. The boolean return simplifies this in case you don't care about the specific error that caused the issue. The `error_code`, whether thrown or in a parameter, gives you more details.

So, to answer your question:

1. It returns true if successful, false otherwise
2. If you want details on the error, you can either get it from an exception or from the `error_code` parameter. Keep in mind that this may be system-dependent.

Comment: How does it simplify anything? If the function always throws on error, then it effectively *never* returns `false`.

Comment: So basically, the version that does not take the error_code, will never return false and any code that branches based of that result is dead code.

Comment: Also, I was asking specifically about the version without the error_code.

Comment: @Angew I was wondering the same, but it can be helpful in bigger blocks. What I said here is based on my experience on using it. Yes, rioki, it will never return false. However, I always put it in an if block, in case there's some implementation dependence.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `copy_file(a,b)` is just an overload to `copy_file(a,b,copy_options::none)` which will always return `true` *or* throw an exception.  But when you use, e.g., `copy_file(a,b,copy_options::skip_existing)` you can also recieve valid `false` with no exception, thus you know the destination file already existed.

Comment: Let me rephrase that a bit: *Other* functions in the `copy_file` overload set return a `bool` that may be `false`, so *this* function also returns a `bool`, for consistency, even though it is never `false`. It is a contentious but *somewhat* justifiable design decision.